# Multipoint impedance matching to RF plasma

Tags: electrical-resistance, plasma-physics, radio-frequency

When dealing with RF plasma sources - one of the most significant challenges is impedance matching between RF power source and plasma. Impedance of plasma changes dramatically during ignition - and this change is very fast.

I wonder if it is possible to build impedance matching circuit which is matched to both cold & hot plasma at the same time without tuning, even if it requires more components (i.e. more than 2C + 1L)? So that when plasma starts to burn - circuit is immediately matched to it.

If it is not possible - are there any hacks/tricks to make it work relatively well with both states of plasma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to design and test RF impedance matching units for plasma generation.

The matching unit is essentially a resonant LC network, tuned to the RF frequency and delivering an output impedance to match that of the plasma chamber; the resonant frequency and output impedance are interdependent. As you note, the chamber impedance changes dramatically on striking the plasma. It is impossible to tune a resonant LC circuit to two output impedances simultaneously. The solutions available are:

- Lower the Q of the resonator by broadening its frequency range. But this lowers the peak voltage correspondingly and can make it difficult to strike a plasma. One approach is to insert a modest resistance somewhere the current is high during operation, but low until the plasma is struck. It needs an over-specced power supply to overcome the low Q and will also waste significant power as heat, and so is only viable for small lab units.
- Switch circuit elements in and out. This requires either high-current or high-voltage switching, and so tends to be expensive and/or high-maintenance, and again suited only to small lab rigs. It also risks parasitic resonances that can suck power back out of the plasma and mess everything up.
- Use variable components, such as variable capacitors and/or variable inductors. A reflectometer (measuring forward and reflected power) is necessary in order to maintain tuning of the circuit to the RF frequency. This has the great advantage of flexibility if chamber conditions are changed, and is the usual approach. Matching adjustments may be manual, or automated via analogue hardware or digital software. Although the high-impedance setting of the unit can be calculated, you usually have to refine the most reliable ignition position for each initial chamber condition by trial-and-error.

After that, it's more down to engineering than to physics.

Comment: Guy, this is a perfect answer, and you are the perfect "Guy" to provide it. We used to sputter thin films at HP when I worked there, but I was the customer for the films and not the producer, so I didn't have to run the RF systems. But as a ham radio operator I enjoy the benefits of the automatch system in my Yaesu FT-450, which does the Z match at any frequency in its range at the push of a button!

Comment: Thanks. The fun bit was mucking about with the gas pressure and creating ball lightning when the boss wasn't looking. Ended up with two balls on opposite sides of the chamber, circling round each other. Good times.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Would you have a book recommandation (grad or undergrad level) about impedance matching for RF plasmas? If it includes plasma models and some matching circuit designs with formulas (how to choose C or L value for example) that would be great

Answer (score 1):

One way to do a crude match is to have a dropping resistor in series with the RF so that when the plasma ignites and its resistance drops, the resistor "catches" the load and limits the current.

The reason I suggest this is that although fully automatic impedance matchers are in use for ham radio transmitters, it takes several seconds for the circuitry to respond and patch in the correct amount of inductance or capacitance to obtain a match, and then engage the power amp into the load. In the meantime, the "ballast resistor" does the work.